# Moving money around the world

Tags: united-states, europe, china, interactive-brokers, brazil

I was born in Brazil, also have Luxembourg citizenship. I have US based IBKR account (starting to play with it) linked to my current address in China. I'm working and saving money in bank in China. Currently I have RMB 100K to 200K and I'm 35 to 40.

I'm planning to buy a house/apartment in Europe, perhaps no early then 5 years from now. Perhaps I'll move to live/work in EU next year.

How should invest, given the information above? May I provide additional information?

Comment: The goal is to invest the money instead of keeping it in a bank account. The difficulty is to find the best investment, since that might take to long avoiding the bad ones is already good.

Comment: What is your risk appetite?  Are you willing to have your money locked in a fund for 10 years?  These details matter.

Comment: I'm seeking no risk and I'll definitely feel better not having money locked. From my quick research, it seems VOO ETF domiciled in Ireland might be a good bet although I'm not sure yet. Why did you mention a fund instead of an ETF?

Comment: You should include that information in the question itself.